# Unable to install PySpark Module Error No Module Found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to work with Microsofts Hyperspace application.

In order to make it work with Python I need to install the module called Hyperspace.

When I implement the code `from hyperspace import *` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hyperspace'
```

I tried the following but still no luck

```
from pyspark hyperspace import *
```

Can someone let me know what it will take to successfully install the module?

I

Thanks

Comment: This was resolved by installing com.microsoft.hyperspace:hyperspace-core_2.11:
0.2.0

However, when I run the following line of code ```hyperspace.createIndex(emp_DF, emp_IndexConfig)``` I get the error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SerializableFileStatus cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just so you know, I'm trying to run this code from Databricks, Apache Spark. I think the problem is Databricks uses DBFS as its filesystem whereas it would appear the application can only be run in HDSF

Comment: what runtime version is used?

Comment: @AlexOtt, thanks for reaching out. I have been informed that Hyperspace isn't supported on Databricks DBFS file system.So I will close out this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module isn't supported on Databricks